# Passcode for access to a PHP app, no database access needed

Tags: php

I'm making a simple PHP app where I'd like the users to enter a passcode to enter the site.  The users won't be interacting with a database or anything like that.  I just want access limited to those with the passcode.

I'm sure I can make something with a simple conditional statement, and a session, but I wonder if there is a best practice for something like this that I'm unaware of.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, if you need single password for everyone you are better of using HTTP authentication, which in Apache is done by .htaccess file.

More about that, with an example included at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html